# Is there way to return 3 elements in one return?

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, expo, element

I try to return the following 3 elements in the following order but it doesn't work for me:
i want to return the AzureLoginView and the view and only than i want return 
the PlacesNavigator and the modal

```
render() {

    if (!this.state.loginSuccess) {

      return (
        <AzureLoginView
          azureInstance={this.azureInstance}
          loadingMessage={<Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" }}>waiting...</Text>}
          onSuccess={this._onLoginSuccess}
        />
      )
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              textAlign: 'center'
            }}> conect to-{"\n"}{givenName + " " + surname}</Text>
          </View>
);

    }
    const { userPrincipalName, givenName, surname } = this.state.azureLoginObject;
    return (
      <PlacesNavigator /> ,
      <Modal />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap them in a surrounding `<div>` or a [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) element.

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

Try the following - based on the comment section, just updated the order or components:

```
return (
    <>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={{
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'center'
          }}> conect to-{"\n"}{givenName + " " + surname}</Text>
        </View>
        <Modal />
        <PlacesNavigator />
    </>
);
```

In this way it will return in that way as you want all the components what you added into `render`.

I hope that helps!

Comment: i need return the view first then the modal and than  the placenavigator..
how can i do that ?

Comment: @zibi then you reorder the elements how you need them.

Comment: its return me everything together and i need it will return the view first and than the others

Comment: @zibi Could you please help me understand what do you mean by return the view first and than the others? Do you mean some kind of delay or not as the answer providing the solution? I mean if you place between the `<></>` fragment in your specific order than it returns in that order. Additionally I have updated my answer to return in that order as you suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @norbitrial said, you need to surround them in a `<div>` or a `React.Fragment` element. Or you can return an array of elements like this

```
if (this.state.loginSuccess) {
      return ([
        <Modal /> ,

        <PlacesNavigator /> ,

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={{
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'center'
          }}> conect to-{"\n"}{givenName + " " + surname}</Text>
        </View>


        // 

      ]);
    }
```